# Multiple nonlinear regression in R using nls, getting a bunch of errors

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to follow the methodology of Nolan and Hitt (2006) to predict well nitrate concentrations (well = STNM, Y = nitrate concentration). Below are some of the predictive variables I'm using. X represents nitrogen loading variables (e.g., fertilizer load, septic tanks), Z represents transport variables (e.g., soil Ksat), and z represents attenuation (e.g., soil carbon, % wetlands).

This is a linear submodel with nonlinear multiplicative terms:

```
Y = sum(xi*bi) * sum(exp(Zi*ai)) * sum(exp(xi*di))
```

where b, a, and d are the parameters. I have 8 X variables and parameters, 5 Z variables and parameters, and 5 z variables and parameters. Below is a sample of the head of my data (didn't include Z3-5 or z1-5).

```
STNM    Y     X1     X2      X3    X4    X5    X6   X7 X8    Z1  Z2
A-0071 0.49 216.45   0.00  233.03 17.15  0.00 33.87 6.97 37  0.00 113
A-0420 0.00  23.88   0.00   39.15 23.85  0.00  0.00 6.91  0  0.00 190
A-0421 0.01 167.00 114.72  295.03 27.18  4.87  3.62 7.00  2  0.00 132
A-0436 0.38 216.45   0.00  233.03 17.15  0.00 33.87 6.97 37  0.00  52
A-0725 0.04  13.94   0.00   22.86 22.86  0.00  0.00 7.07  0 57.41  40
M-0013 0.00 494.77 549.91 1045.28  1.21 10.31  1.34 6.93 18  0.00 225
```

Now for my question, when I try to run nls I use the following code:

```
m <- nls(y ~ ((X1*b1)+(X2*b2)+(X3*b3)+(X4*b4)+(X5*b5)+(X6*b6)+(X7*b7)+(X8*b8))*(exp(Z1*a1)+exp(Z2*a2)+exp(Z3*a3)+exp(Z4*a4)+exp(Z5*a5))*(exp(z1*d1)+exp(z2*d2)+exp(z3*d3)+exp(z4*d4)+exp(z5*d5)), data=data, start = list(b1=.0001,b2=.0001,b3=0,b4=0,b5=0,b6=.00072,b7=0,b8=.00095,a1=-0.0547,a2=0.01,a3=-.149,a4=-.19,a5=-.19,d1=-20,d2=-20,d3=-50,d4=-3,d5=-1))
```

and I get the following errors:

> Error in qr.qty(QR, resid) : 
>     'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In lhs - rhs :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
> 2: In .swts * attr(rhs, "gradient") :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I've searched a bunch of answers and none of the situations seem to apply to me, but I admittedly don't know what I'm doing too well. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With only 6 rows it can be fit exactly. `nls` does not support zero residual problems but if we eliminate all but `X1`, `X2`, `Z1` and `Z2` then we can make it work.  We have also used `alg = "plinear"` to avoid having to provide starting values for th linear parameters, i.e. the `b` parameters.  Assuming you have many more rows you might be able to get it to work without dropping so much.

```
Lines <- "STNM    Y     X1     X2      X3    X4    X5    X6   X7 X8    Z1  Z2
A-0071 0.49 216.45   0.00  233.03 17.15  0.00 33.87 6.97 37  0.00 113
A-0420 0.00  23.88   0.00   39.15 23.85  0.00  0.00 6.91  0  0.00 190
A-0421 0.01 167.00 114.72  295.03 27.18  4.87  3.62 7.00  2  0.00 132
A-0436 0.38 216.45   0.00  233.03 17.15  0.00 33.87 6.97 37  0.00  52
A-0725 0.04  13.94   0.00   22.86 22.86  0.00  0.00 7.07  0 57.41  40
M-0013 0.00 494.77 549.91 1045.28  1.21 10.31  1.34 6.93 18  0.00 225"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

# X <- as.matrix(data[3:10])
X <- as.matrix(data[3:4])
fo <- Y ~ X * (exp(Z1*a1)+exp(Z2*a2))
st <- list(a1 = -0.0547, a2 = 0.01)
fm <- nls(fo, data = data, start = st, alg = "plinear")
```

giving:

```
> fm
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ X * (exp(Z1 * a1) + exp(Z2 * a2))
   data: data
        a1         a2    .lin.X1    .lin.X2 
 0.0134006  0.0018094  0.0008874 -0.0008142 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.02057

Number of iterations to convergence: 10 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.441e-06
```